# JS Discord Bot Get Role

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get a role without using messages, like:

```
     const Discord = require('discord.js');
     const Bot = new Discord.Client();
     const Role = Discord.roles.find('name,'Exemple')

     Role.delete()
```

Is this possible to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can but you will need to have the guild id you want to get the role from. Also, you should put that part in the `ready` event.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot online!");
    const guild = client.guilds.get("The_server_id");
    const role = guild.roles.find("name", "Your_role_name");

    console.log(`Found the role ${role.name}`);
})
```

Comment: find("name", "Your_role_name") is deprecated, refer to StanB answer instead

Comment: Yes it is deprecated and the new way of doing it is. `const role = guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === 'Your_role_name');`

Answer (score 10):

Using that way of `Collection#find("key", "value")` in Discord.JS is deprecated by the way,
You should use `Collection#find(Obj => Obj.key == "value")` instead.

Comment: That's good to know, but did that change in the year since the other answer was accepted? Since SO is a repository of historical knowledge, this answer could be improved by adding a reference that indicates when it became deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

I tried with the posted solution but `client.guilds.get` was not recognized as a function:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function at Client.

Checking the content of `client.guilds` I found 'cache' object:

```js
GuildManager {
  cacheType: [Function: Collection],
  cache: Collection [Map] {
    '<discord server id>' => Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      (...)
     }
  }
}
```

The solution was:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    const myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('<discord server id>');
    const myRole = myGuild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '<role name>');
    console.log(`Found the role ${myRole.name}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guild doesn't work unless you have it set up on the server. People keep suggesting this but you have to already have infrastructure set up in your discord server.

Answer (score 0):

`const role = guild.roles.cache.get('role_id');`

This seems to be working in the latest API version.

Answer (score 0):

To get an specific role i use this code.
Replace SERVER_ID with your server id and ROLE_NAME with the name of the role

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("SERVER_ID");
const role = guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "ROLE_NAME");

console.log(`Found the role ${role.name}`);
console.log(`Found the role ${role.id}`);
```